# trouble accessing child object property in express js

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

my api at

http://52.24.34.186:3000/api/posts/

========================================================

```
router.route('/users/root/:id').get(function(req, res) {
   User.findOne()
  .populate('countryId')
  .populate('stateId')
  .populate('districtId')
  .populate('mandalId')
  .populate('villageId')
  exec({villageId._id: req.params.id}, function(err, userObj) {
  if (err) {
    return res.send(err);
  }
  res.json(userObj);
});
});
```

==> Showing error as "Unexpected Token . "

at "exec({villageId._id: req.params.id}, function(err, userObj) {"

Please anybody help me out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a `.` before `exec(`.

Also, `villageId._id` is an invalid property name. Perhaps you meant to use just `{ villageId: req.params.id }` ?

Comment: thanks for your answer. even after keeping dot before exec() i am getting the same error.

Comment: You may be right. But i need to check 'req.params.id' with my villageId._id not _id. How to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "check 'req.params.id' with my villageId._id?"

Comment: check my json object from http://52.24.34.186:3000/api/posts/

I need to write an api to get posts filter by villageId._id.

Comment: Finally i got the solution. I need to use "villageId" instead of "villageId._id". Thanks